# European services similar to http://internetpulse.net?

Tags: networking, monitoring

Is there a website which monitors European carriers similar to http://internetpulse.net does for USA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's exactly the same, but we use this to check if there are link-problems:

http://www.internettrafficreport.com/europe.htm

Comment: Thanks! but these do not seem to be core routers. any more suggestions?